# Simplifying null checks with inplace OR

Tags: python, null, in-place

I am simplifying some null/false checks in python in the following form:

This:

```
if not a:
    a = 'foo'
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
a = a or 'foo'
```

And, looking above is natural to try to simplify even further, like this:

```
a |= 'foo'
```

But, the python's in-place `or` is actually doing in-place bitwise or:

```
a = None
a |= 'foo'
=> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

a = 'foo'
a |= 'bar'
=> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'str' and 'str'

a = 1
a |= 2
print a
=> 3

a = 2
a |= 3
print a
=> 3
```

So, the questions are: Does Python has an inplace or? Also, do you see problems doing a simplified null/false check like this?

#### Disclaimer

I am aware that `a is not None` is not the same as `not a`. The former evaluates if a is indeed not a `None` value while the latter evaluates if a is not something that evaluates to `False` (like `False`, `None`, `0`, `''` (empty string), `[]`, `{}` (empty collections) and so on)

Comment: "python's in-place or is actually doing in-place binary addition" -> No, it's not, it's doing in-place bitwise OR.

Comment: `name |= val` is the equivalent of `name = name | val` (more or less). `|` is **not** the boolean `or` operator, it is the bitwise or  operator.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote binary addition but was thinking of the `bitwise circuit addition` or simply the `bitwise or`. Anyway I made an edit to my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want because there isn't an inplace logical `or`, but I don't think you really want to anyway. In Python "readability counts", and `a or= b` or whatever is definitely very difficult to read. `a = a or 5` is quite a common idiom, and so isn't *too* unreadable, but `or=` I think definitely would be. For this reason, I think it is worth doing `if a is not None` instead. In answer to your question about possible dangers of `a = a or default`, the only one I can think of is if `default` has a Boolean value of `False` then it breaks.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with you about the readability part. I would probably abort the `|=` even if it would possible to use it because of the same reason. Anyway, curiosity struck me

Answer (score 3):

Python does not have an in-place logical `or`, only the bitwise version you are already using.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is an in-place or.

As for `a = a or 'foo'`, I've seen it and use it often. As far as I know it's a common idiom. It's explicit and the behavior is pretty obvious so I'm not aware of any PEP guidelines that it breaks. I actually find it more readable than `a |= 'foo` since it doesn't resort to rare-ish operators and reads naturally.

Comment: If I could, I would choose both your and sweeneyrod's answer as the accept ones. They are quite the same but as his answer is a bit more complete, I am accepting his